# Optimizing Three.js text performance (merge geometries, shaders, etc)

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl, gsap

I've made an initial attempt to streamline the creation of 3D text using Three.js (r75).

Searching for webGL and Three.js performance best practices I have found the topics of **merging geometries** and **utilizing shaders** to be most prevalent so far.

1. **Merging Geometries**:
   http://www.jbernier.com/merging-geometries-in-three-js

   Currently the live demo is creating a separate geometry for each text mesh. My understanding is that performance can be increased by combining all geometries into a single mesh, which I've been unable to accomplish. My intention is to utilize each letter as an object for individual control.
2. **Utilizing Shaders**
   Can performance of webGL text be increased by utilizing shaders? My aim is to make use of 3D text in web development projects to the full extent that browsers are capable.

Any other performance gains that can be made without sacrificing the current presentation are greatly appreciated.

Here's the live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uuL6Lrms/

```
    /* global variables */
var camera , cameraTarget , renderer ,
    pointLight , hex ,
    stats , rendererStats , controls , reCenterTimeout ,
    winWidth , winHeight ,
    typeface = 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/redwavedesign/ccb20f24e7399f3d741e49fbe23add84/raw/402bcf913c55ad6b12ecfdd20c52e3047ff26ace/bebas_regular.typeface.js';

/* default text values */
var defaults = {
    fN: 'bebas_regular' ,   // font
    h: 8 ,                  // height
    s: 28 ,                 // size
    cS: 4 ,                 // curveSegments
    bT: 1 ,                 // bevelThickness
    bSz: 1.5 ,              // bevelSize
    bSg: 3 ,                // bevelSegmants
    bE: true ,              // bevelEnabled
    c: '#3c3c3c' ,          // color
    y: -64 ,
    z: -1
}


/* scene object for convenience */
var scene = {
    backgroundColor: '#000000' ,
    cameraX: 0 ,
    cameraY: 0 ,
    cameraZ: 950 ,
    pointLightIntensity: 0
}


/* text objects */

var prisonref = {
    t: 'PRISONREF.COM' ,    // text
    h: 20.75 ,              // height
    s: 71.25 ,              // size
    cSg: 4 ,                // curveSegments
    bT: 1 ,                 // bevelThickness
    bS: 1.5 ,               // bevelSize
    bSg: 3 ,                // bevelSegments
    bE: true ,              // bevelEnabled
    x: 'centered' ,
    y: -27 ,
    z: -14 ,
    font: undefined
}

var ref1 = {
    t: 'REF' ,
    x: -310 ,
}

var use = {
    t: 'USE' ,
    c: '#8c8c8c' ,          // color
    x: -252
}

var ref2 = {
    t: 'REF' ,
    x: -192 ,
}

var ine = {
    t: 'INE' ,
    c: '#8c8c8c' ,
    x: -134 ,
}

var ref3 = {
    t: 'REF' ,
    x: -85 ,
}

var ocus = {
    t: 'OCUS' ,
    c: '#8c8c8c' ,
    x: -27
}

var ref4 = {
    t: 'REF' ,
    x: 54
}

var orm = {
    t: 'ORM' ,
    c: '#8c8c8c' ,
    x: 112
}

var ref5 = {
    t: 'REF' ,
    x: 181
}

var eree = {
    t: 'EREE' ,
    c: '#8c8c8c' ,
    x: 238
}


// array with all text objects
var texts = [ prisonref , ref1 , use , ref2 , ine , ref3 , ocus , ref4 , orm , ref5 , eree ];


function decimalToHex( d ) {

    var hex = Number( d ).toString( 16 );
    hex = "000000".substr( 0, 6 - hex.length ) + hex;
    return hex.toUpperCase();

}


function init() {

    /* create scene, camera and renderer */
    scene.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera =  new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40 , window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight , .1 , 1500 ); // or 20
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });

    /* setup renderer */
    renderer.setClearColor( scene.backgroundColor );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight );
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;

    /* setup camera */
    camera.position.set( scene.cameraX , scene.cameraY , scene.cameraZ );
    cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3( 0 , 0 , 0 );

    /* Lights */
    pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, scene.pointLightIntensity );
    pointLight.position.set( 0 , 80 , 200 );
    scene.scene.add( pointLight );

    pointLight.color.setStyle( 'rgb( 255, 255, 255 )' );
    hex = decimalToHex( pointLight.color.getHex() );

    /* add controls */
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera , renderer.domElement );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change' , function() {

        clearTimeout( reCenterTimeout );

        reCenterTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            reCenterText();
        }, 5000 );

        render();

    });

    // load each text object from the 'texts' array
    loadAllText( texts );


    // add the rendered element to the page
    $( '#webGL-container' ).append( renderer.domElement );


    // Tween text into position
    bringInText();

}


function loadAllText( texts ) {

    for( t = 0 ; t < texts.length ; t++ ) {

        loadFont( texts[ t ] );

    }

}


function loadFont( text ) {

    var fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();

    fontLoader.load( typeface , function ( response ) {

        text.f = response;

        refreshText( text );

    });

}


function createText( text ) {
    var f = text.f ,
        s = text.s || defaults.s ,
        h = text.h || defaults.h ,
        cSg = text.cSg || defaults.cSg ,
        bT = text.bT || defaults.bT ,
        bSz = text.bSz || defaults.bSz ,
        bSg = text.bSg || defaults.bSg ,
        bE = text.bE || defaults.bE ,
        c = text.c || defaults.c ,
        y = text.y || defaults.y ,
        z = text.z || defaults.z;

    text.geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( text.t , {

        font: f,
        height: h ,
        size: s ,
        curveSegments: cSg ,
        bevelThickness: bT,
        bevelSize: bSz ,
        bevelSegments: bSg ,
        bevelEnabled: bE ,
        material: 0,
        extrudeMaterial: 1

    });

    text.material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( [
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: c , shading: THREE.FlatShading } ), // front
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: c , shading: THREE.SmoothShading } ) // side
    ] );

    text.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    text.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    text.centerOffset = -0.5 * ( text.geometry.boundingBox.max.x - text.geometry.boundingBox.min.x );

    if( text.x == 'centered' ) text.x = text.centerOffset;

    text.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( text.geometry, text.material );

    text.mesh.position.set( text.x , y , z );

    // add text object to scene
    // looking for a way to combine all text meshes in a single geometry call
    scene.scene.add( text.mesh );

}


function refreshText( text ) {

    scene.scene.remove( text.mesh );

    createText( text );

}


function render() {

    camera.lookAt( cameraTarget );

    renderer.clear();

    renderer.render( scene.scene , camera );

}


function animate() {

    // begin Three.js stats utility
    stats.begin();

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

    renderer.render( scene.scene , camera );

    // update Threex stats plugin
    rendererStats.update( renderer );

    // conclude sample for Three.js stats testing
    stats.end();

}


// performance monitoring

rendererStats = new THREEx.RendererStats();
rendererStats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute'
rendererStats.domElement.style.left = '0px'
rendererStats.domElement.style.bottom   = '0px'
document.body.appendChild( rendererStats.domElement );

stats = new Stats();
stats.setMode( 1 );
document.body.appendChild( stats.domElement );


    // greensock tweening

function bringInText() {
    var introTimeline = new TimelineMax({ 
        paused: true ,
        delay: .1
    });

    introTimeline

        .to( pointLight , 2.3 , {
            intensity: 1.6 ,

            ease: Power2.easeIn
        }, '.3' )

        .to( camera.position , 3 , {
            z: 650
        }, '0' )

    .play();

}


function reCenterText() {
    var reCenterTimeline = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });

    reCenterTimeline

        .to( camera.position , 2 , {
            x: 0 ,
            y: 0 ,
            z: 650
        }, '0' )

    .play();

}


// initialize 
init();

// animate
animate();


// update camera-aspect and renderer-size on window resize
$( window ).resize(function() {

    var winHeight = window.innerHeight ,
        winWidth = window.innerWidth;

    camera.aspect = winWidth / winHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( winWidth , winHeight );

});
```

Thank You!